# Defining links for subfolder pages

Tags: asp.net, html, url, hyperlink, href

I have defined CSS in MasterPage so that all pages can use the same style. For some reason I defined an inline style for menu.

I provide a relative link for pages like this:

```
<ul>
<li style="left: -1px; top: 0px; width: 90px"><a href="Home.aspx">Home</a></li>
....
...
...</ul>
```

"Home.aspx" is in the root directory. The link mentioned above works fine if I am accessing it from the root directory but if I try to access it from a sub-folder it shows an error: `HTTP Error 404 - Not Found`.

How can "Home.aspx" be accessed from the root directory and a sub-folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**
You should use asp Hyperlink control for this case, & provide.

```
NavigateUrl = "~/Home.aspx"
```

**Solution 2:**
Alternatively you can use `../Home.aspx` for anchor tag in sub folder (level 1) add `../` for each sub folder level.

Comment: Thanks much bro. You save my lot of times. Your first solution works finely for me. 
And how i can implement your second solution as i have mentioned the links once.